# TimePicker UWP Basics

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

Having some problems with a simple clock application I am trying to write.  Very new to UWP and C# so patience is greatly appreciated.  Took source from https://github.com/kd4gar/Windows-Core-IOT-Clock

What I am trying to do is have the clock font/brightness autodim at night based upon set time.  So I am using TimePicker

In the Settings.XAML I have a few other settings (24 hour clock, etc) and the settings page works, I have these two items:

In my .xaml.cs  I have this code.  I am trying to save it to settings, or set the default values to 7:00 AM and 17:00 AM.

```
    public DateTime DimDisplayStartTimeSetting
    {
        get
        {

            if (localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"] == null)
            {
                localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"] = "7:00";
            }
            ///  return (localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"]);
            return (localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"]);

            localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"] = "7:00";
        }

        set
        {
            localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"] = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime DimDisplayStopTimeSetting
    {
        get
        {

            if (localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"] == null)
            {
                localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"] = "17:00";
            }
            /// return TimeSpan.Parse(localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"].ToString());

        }

        set
        {
            localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"] = value;
        }
    }
```

I seem to be doing something wrong, specifically around using DateTime vs TimeSpan.  Could someone help me understand a bit better?  I've read through the docs on TimePicker and think I understand that it wants a TimeSpan, but not sure how to set it right in my Settings.xaml.cs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` stores the exact date and time of the day (e.g., 2017-10-12 17:00), whereas `TimeSpan` stores the length of the period of time (e.g., 2 hours 1 minute 5 seconds or 3 days).

If you don't need to store a specific date in settings, only the time of day (which seems to be the case), then go with the `TimeSpan`:

```
    public TimeSpan DimDisplayStartTimeSetting
    {
        get
        {

            if (!localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"))
                localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"] = TimeSpan.FromHours(7);

            return (TimeSpan) localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"];
        }

        set
        {
            localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStartTimeSettingValue"] = value;
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan DimDisplayStopTimeSetting
    {
        get
        {

            if (!localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"))
                localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"] = new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0);

            return (TimeSpan) localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"];
        }

        set
        {
            localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Here `TimeSpan.FromHours(7);` and `new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0);` do the same job - create a new `TimeSpan` object, but you can always pick the syntax that fits the situation better.

Local settings container is capable of storing `TimeSpan` objects, but it returns everything as `object`, so we have to manually cast the returned value to `TimeSpan` type, like in this line:

```
return (TimeSpan) localSettings.Values["DimDisplayStopTimeSettingValue"];
```

Local settings container doesn't support `DateTime` objects though, but if you decide that you need to store them instead of `TimeSpan`s, you can always convert them to `DateTimeOffset` type, which is supported by the container.

You can read more about the differences between date and time types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime).